# Javascript checkbox to change background not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, background-position

I'm trying to change the background position of an element using a checkbox, but is not working.

Here is the code:

```js
x = false;

function Check() {
  if (x) {
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition = '-28px 0';
    x = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition = 'none';
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
    x = true;
  }

}
```

```css
#checkboz {
  background: url(http://movimientomore.com/images/2016/12/21/sprite-check-01.png);
  background-size: 55px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboz" class="checkbox">
  <label for="modlgn-remember">
    <input id="modlgn-remember" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" type="checkbox">Recordarme</label>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: How you call your function? You didn't invoked function at all?

Comment: Add `onclick="Check()"` to the checkbox.

Comment: Check() is never being called.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an eventlistener or onclick in your code.

```
document.getElementById("checkboz").addEventListener("click", Check);
```

```js
x=false;
function Check(){
  x=!x;
  if(x){    
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition='0 0';
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition='-28px 0';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition='none'; 
    document.getElementById("checkboz").style.backgroundPosition='0 0';   
  }


}
document.getElementById("checkboz").addEventListener("click", Check);
```

```css
#checkboz{
  background: url(http://movimientomore.com/images/2016/12/21/sprite-check-01.png);
  background-size: 55px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboz" class="checkbox">
  <label for="modlgn-remember"><input id="modlgn-remember" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" type="checkbox">Recordarme</label>
</div>
```

Or view on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/y25ddb1r/)

Read up: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Updated the code so it is embedded on this post, as well as corrected an error with the intended toggle value for the background. (checked when checked,  clear when unchecked).  The other code had it do nothing on first check, then it was checked when the box was unchecked.

Comment: I'm new to answering questions, thanks for the edit.

Comment: This answer looks better :)

Comment: @RahulDesai - I was just going to ask you to add that (the MDN link), as it was the one thing you provided in your solution that this one didn't have and could use :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle to show a working version of the functionality you are seeking.

[Your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kchqhntf/8/)

Like others have said in the comments, the Check function was never being called, but additionally, it is better to swap classes out on the elements instead of trying to manually manipulate the styles.

```
    var element = document.getElementById('modlgn-remember');
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
        console.log(element.checked)
        Check(element.checked);
    }, false);
    x=false;
    function Check(checked){
      console.log(x);
      var $el = document.getElementById("checkboz")
      if(checked){
        $el.className = $el.className.replace(' remove-background- position-1 remove-background-position-2', '');  
        $el.className += ' add-background-position-1 add-background-position-2';
       x=false;
      } else {
        var cn = $el.className;
        cn = $el.className.replace(' add-background-position-1 add-background-position-2', '');  
        $el.className = cn;
        $el.className += ' remove-background-position-1 remove-background-position-2';
        x=true;    
      }  
   }
```

With the following css classes:

```
    .add-background-position-1 {
      background-position: 0 0 !important;
    }

    .add-background-position-2 {
      background-position: -28px 0 !important;
    }
    .remove-background-position-1 {
      background-position: inherit !important;
    }
    .remove-background-position-2 {
      background-position: 0 0 !important;
    }
```

without the !important on the css classes the existing background style will take precedence over the new classes.

I hope that help!